# Android SDK environment in Ubuntu

Tags: android-sdk

While running `./distribute.sh -m kivy` command, I got the following error:

```
$ ./distribute.sh -m kivy
Check build dependencies for Ubuntu
Check enviromnent
No ANDROIDSDK environment set, abort
```

Comment: Please state your problem in details!

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297345/no-android-sdk-environment-set-for-kivy-in-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

Quoting:

> After installing them, export both installation path, NDK version and API to use:
>
> ```
> export ANDROIDSDK=/path/to/android-sdk
> export ANDROIDNDK=/path/to/android-ndk
> export ANDROIDNDKVER=rX
> export ANDROIDAPI=X
>
> # example
> export ANDROIDSDK="/home/tito/code/android/android-sdk-linux_86"
> export ANDROIDNDK="/home/tito/code/android/android-ndk-r7"
> export ANDROIDNDKVER=r7
> export ANDROIDAPI=14
> ```
>
> Also, you must configure you’re PATH to add the android binary:
>
> ```
> export PATH=$ANDROIDNDK:$ANDROIDSDK/platform-tools:$ANDROIDSDK/tools:$PATH
> ```

Set all the necessary variables (add them to `~/.profile`).